# How compatible dash is with ksh?

Tags: command-line, sh, ksh, posix-compliant

Can I make `/bin/sh` symlinked to `/bin/ksh` instead of `/bin/dash` without breaking anything in the process ?  Since they're both supposed to be POSIX-compliant, can I reasonably expect the replacement to go without issues?

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh` was bash for years on Ubuntu, and FWIW it is [ksh93 on newer versions of Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/userenv-1.html), so most things should work. If anything, POSIX modes on advanced shells like ksh are more liberal than dash, so some new features are still available:

```
~ for shell in dash bash ksh zsh; do ARGV0=sh POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 $shell -c 'echo -n $0 {a,b,c}; [[ -z $POSIXL_CORRECT ]] && echo typo'; done
sh {a,b,c}sh: 1: [[: not found
sh a b ctypo
-n sh a b c
typo
sh {a,b,c}typo
$ for shell in dash bash ksh zsh; do ARGV0=sh $shell -c 'echo -n $0 {a,b,c}; [[ -z $POSIXL_CORRECT ]] && echo typo'; done
sh {a,b,c}sh: 1: [[: not found
sh a b ctypo
sh a b ctypo
sh {a,b,c}typo
```

I don't think any script from a package in Ubuntu relies on dash's *lack* of brace expansion. A quick scan of scripts in my `/usr/bin` doesn't show anything like that. There are other modern features available on POSIX-modes of ksh and bash, so it's difficult to predict without actually running the scripts with those shells.

I don't see any benefit to making `/bin/sh` be ksh, though.